# Javascript works on Chrome, but no on IE or FF

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I have a Javascript code on my page that counts time since the user logged on.
I'm using the script from [here](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)
The thing is the on Chrome, the script works perfectly, but on IE or FF it won't work.
Is there anyway I can make it work on all 3 browsers?
Thank you!

[image]

My code:
Javascript: (the %%DATE%% is replaced by a string like: `2011-07-25 14:12:59`

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function parse_date(string) {  
    var date = new Date();  
    var parts = String(string).split(/[- :]/);  

    date.setFullYear(parts[0]);  
    date.setMonth(parts[1] - 1);  
    date.setDate(parts[2]);  
    date.setHours(parts[3]);  
    date.setMinutes(parts[4]);  
    date.setSeconds(parts[5]);  
    date.setMilliseconds(0);  

    return date;  
}  

//$(function () {
//  var austDay = new Date();
//  austDay = new Date("%%DATE%%");
//  austDay.setSeconds(austDay.getSeconds()+3);
//  $('#time_square').countdown({since: austDay, format: 'MS', compact: true});
//});

function set_time() {
    var austDay = new Date();
    austDay = new Date("%%DATE%%");
    austDay.setSeconds(austDay.getSeconds()+3);
    $('#time_square').countdown({since: austDay, format: 'MS', compact: true});
};

function validate()
{
  var retval = false;
  for (var i=0; i < document.form.r.length; i++)
  {
    if (document.form.r[i].checked)
    {
      retval = true;
    }
  }  

  return retval;
}

function set_interval() {
setInterval("set_time()",100);
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body bgcolor="#000000" topmargin="0" onload="set_interval()">

<table width="166" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="45"><font color="#FFFFFF" size="5px">Time:</font></td>
    <td width="111"><div id="time_square"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what error do is IE telling ? and what the heck is this ? "austDay = new Date("%%DATE%%");"

Comment: I added a screenshot of the error. austDay is set to be the datetime when the user logged in. The %%DATE%% is replaced by the server with the datetime string.

Comment: there must be an error notification in IE , or use Firebug in Firefox - but it hing it will be in date format , try to put there manually date - eg " new Date( 2011, 2-1,10,10,0,0 )"

Comment: I used the parse_date function: austDay = new Date(parse_date("%%DATE%%")); Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using setInterval? Countdown handles that for you, your code is reinitialising the counter ever 100ms.

Comment: The `set_interval()` function is useless, remove that. (Maybe that is the error?)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using setFullYear. though set/getYear is depricated, most of them gives errors.